# How to search twitter users by their description?

Tags: search, twitter, twitter4j, userid, field-description

I am using twitter4j, I am interested to search a specific users by some words that exists in their description/Bio? is it possible to do that?

**for example:**

user that have the description: "full time developer...."
I want him to be retrieved by searching the word "developer"

searchByDescription("developer");

Is there any method to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [read the Twitter documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/get-users-search) you'll see that you can call `users/search` to get this information.

According to the [Twitter4J documentation](http://twitter4j.org/oldjavadocs/2.2.6/twitter4j/api/UserMethods.html) this is the `searchUsers()` function.